# How do I enable a handler with a condition context1 or context2 or context3?

Tags: eclipse

I have a handler tag inside my plugin.xml like below:

```
<handler
    class="fooHandler"
    commandId="fooCommand">
    <enabledWhen>
        <with variable="activeContexts">
           <or>
              <equals value="fooCtxt1"/>
              <equals value="fooCtxt2"/>
              <equals value="fooCtxt3"/>
           </or>
        </with>
    </enabledWhen>
</handler>
```

But its not working! I also tried

```
<iterate operator="or"> 
         <ctxt1/> 
         <ctxt2/> 
         <ctxt3/>
</iterate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
<iterate operator="or">
    <or>
         <ctxt1/> 
         <ctxt2/> 
         <ctxt3/>
    </or>
</iterate>
```

But its weird why operator="or" is not doing its work! and the interesting thing is that if I remove it (operator="or") it refuses to work. very adamant :)